# Is it OK to ask questions just because it may make for a good answer?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Would you trust philosophy.stackexchange to unequivocate something you just read? It *seems* like these are the better questions. But maybe we're aiming too high.

Is it OK to ask questions just because it may make for a good answer? Should the site not be used like that?

Comment: i guess i'm too discussion based. will probably delete my account...

Comment: The question here is totally fine. And asking well answerable questions on books you just read is actually exactly what this site is mainly about imho: clarification.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking alas,,, my point was that i don't ask questions on books i've just read, but books i won't bother reading. tho, thanks.

Comment: Well, the problem I see with that is twofold: First, you'd need to know *what exactly* you want to ask at all. Second, you'd need to be able to frame the question and at least give an idea why this question should arise in context of the book. Without having read it, both is much asked, especially when dealing with some of the more interesting books in/on philosophy.

Comment: I can see objective value in asking questions that have good answers even if you aren't honestly curious about the question. Specifically, SE sites get a huge amount of their traffic from google search results, so good questions that might be asked by multiple people will help get traffic to the site which attracts more users and keeps the cycle going. Even if you're only asking because the answer would be good, you're still contributing to the over all quality of the site and creating questions other people might find through google.

Comment: I agree with Philip's assessment that you need to know enough about what you're asking to formulate a good question, but if that is achieved I don't see what's wrong with asking a question even if its solely for the purposes of getting a good answer. Most questions are asked to get good answers!